# Use GWT RPC Serialization to send an object from client to server in a POST

Tags: gwt, serialization, rpc

I prefer to use RPC Serialization but then send data using servlets.
We have strangely found that this performs better and it allows us to have general logic for retrying all servlet calls for example.

I have figured out how to send an object from server to client but can't find a way to serialize on client and deserialize on server.

SERVER TO CLIENT

Server:

`serializedObj = RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(DUMMY_METHOD_OF_TYPE_SERIZABLE, object);`

Client:

```
GWT.create(MyRpc.class).createStreamReader(serializedObj).readObject();
```

CLIENT TO SERVER
Client:

```
 SerializationStreamWriter streamWriter = streamFactory.createStreamWriter();
    streamWriter.writeObject(object);
    serializedObj =  streamWriter.toString();
```

But how can I unserialize this after sending it by POST to the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://softteco.blogspot.com/2010/02/serializing-objects-in-gwt-and.html

Note the server side deserialize option

```
    // Getting parameter from request
String content = request.getParameter("content");
// Initializing stream reader
ServerSerializationStreamReader streamReader = new ServerSerializationStreamReader(
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), null);
// Filling stream reader with data
streamReader.prepareToRead(content);
// Reading deserialized object from the stream
dto = (D) streamReader.readObject();
```